# How to add a List of JButtons to a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, layout, addition, jbutton

So... I'm making a Jeopardy game, and I'm experimenting with better ways of making and adding the buttons so that it looks better in the source code. So to start off, I have a CategoryClass that takes the parameters of a List of QuestionButtons (basically a JButton), the category name and so on. The only trouble I'm having is adding the buttons to a JPanel. Here's the code:

```
    public void addCategoryButtons(JPanel pane) {
        JLabel head = this.getCategoryHeading();
        pane.add(head);
        List<QuestionButton> buttons = this.getCategoryButtons();
        for (int i = 0; i < buttons.size(); i++) {
            pane.add(buttons.get(i).getButton());
        }
    }
```

And [here's](http://i.imgur.com/585Ib.png) what I get. Note: the "Test" is the name of the category

As you can see, It shows the last Category I add instead of all of them. Any suggestions?

Comment: It's not clear what the issue is--you're adding a single label "Test", and then there's five buttons. What's *supposed* to happen?

Comment: @DaveNewton So first of all, I'm a noob at StackOverflow and I had no idea for pointing that out for me. Second of all, you don't need to be a jerk and assume everyone knows as much as you. And I won't accept your answer because a better one has bene provided.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Don't just assume that I'm on this 24/7 and will instantly reply to your answers.

Comment: @whowantsakookie I'm sorry, what? Are we supposed to *guess* what's supposed to happen? And you *can't* accept "my answer", because I didn't answer. Where was I a jerk?

Comment: @DaveNewton Have you not seen Jeopardy before?   http://www.atpm.com/8.02/images/jeopardy-starting-board.gif

Comment: @whowantsakookie Nope, but that's not relevant--when you're asking a question, you need to state, explicitly, the differences between what's happening compared with what you expect to happen. You cannot rely on people reading your mind, or watching the same TV programs you do. Where was I being a jerk?

Comment: @DaveNewton It's just a question man.

Comment: @DaveNewton Hey dude, I just read over this post, and I was totally a jerk to you. Sorry about that. I wasn't thinking clearly. Forgive me?

Comment: No worries, I wasn't mad--it happens. Been there myself, we all have. Taking responsibly for it is relatively rare, can't ask for much more than that. Now get off my lawn and go code :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set some layout manager, for example:

```
pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(buttons.size(), 1));
for (int i = 0; i < buttons.size(); i++) 
{
    pane.add(buttons.get(i).getButton());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use a [Layout Manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for this task.